# No Reverse Match When Resetting Password in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement the built in Django authentication views in my site to help with the password resets for users.  I've set the root urls to include the provided URLconf in django.contrib.auth.urls like so:

`path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))`

I've set all the templates in a registration folder in my templates directory.

So, if i go to `/password_reset`, i get the correct page to change my password

If i enter an email, i DO receive the change password email.

If i click the link in the email, i get to the `reset/***/set-password page`

But if i try to enter a new password it submits and goes to `reset/done` but i get following error:

`NoReverseMatch at /reset/done/
Reverse for 'sign_in' not found. 'sign_in' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

I do also have an 'accounts' app in my project which includes a custom 'sign_in' url.  Could this be the issue?  Is this overriding some sort of prebuilt sign_in page from Django?

```
app_name = "accounts"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'sign_in/$', views.sign_in, name='sign_in'),
    url(r'sign_up/$', views.sign_up, name='sign_up'),
    url(r'sign_out/$', views.sign_out, name='sign_out'),
    url(r'profile/$', views.view_profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'profile/change_password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    url(r'favorites/$', views.view_favorites, name='favorites'),
    url(r'^subscribe/', views.subscribe, name = "subscribe"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a pretty easy fix. In settings.py file, i had the `LOGIN_URL` set as `sign_in` when it needed to include the name of the app such as `accounts:sign_in`